# How to fix this n+1 query: Limiting child association to most recent record in JSON api response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-api

I am trying to return a list of parent records, along with each parents most recent child record.

In my controller I have:

```
def index
  projects = current_user.projects.includes(:tasks)

  render json: projects.as_json(
    methods: [:most_recent_task],
  ), status: 200
end
```

The method `most_recent_task` uses an approach articulated [here](https://www.varvet.com/blog/retrieving-the-last-n-ordered-records-with-activerecord/) and summarized below:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  class << self
    def in_order
      order(created_at: :asc)
    end

    def recent(n)
      in_order.endmost(n)
    end

    def endmost(n)
      all.only(:order).from(all.reverse_order.limit(n), table_name)
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks

  def most_recent_task
    tasks.recent(1)[0]
  end
end
```

This approach returns the correct JSON response, but I am now obviously dealing with n+1 queries for `Task` on every request.

I've tried chaining scopes, using `:includes` and `:limit`, but can't seem to crack this nut.  Perhaps using a JSON serializer could solve it?  But I am trying to avoid that extra dependency for now.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to define a has_one with an association scope:

```
has_one :most_recent_task, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }, class_name: "Task"
```

You can then use `includes` to eagerly load the data:

```
>> Project.includes(:most_recent_task).all
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."project_id" IN (1, 2) ORDER BY "tasks"."created_at" ASC
```

Note that it's querying *all* tasks for each project, not just the most recent one.  But there's no N+1, and `Project#most_recent_task` is nicely expressive.

Comment: Ah, this is great. Didn't think about defining an association scope.  Works!

Comment: Great!  Yeah has_one associations are really handy for stuff like this.