# Latest version using PaperTrail gem and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios, paper-trail-gem

I've inherited a project with React and Ruby on Rails. I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to change it so that Rails will be used as an API to the frontend (instead of using Rails views).

I have a model `Item` which uses the PaperTrail gem for versioning. In `items_controller.rb`, I have a `get_items` method which I call via axios from the frontend. This returns all items, with versions including the user object as json.

```rb
def get_items
  @items = Item.all.includes(versions: :user)
  render json: @items.as_json(include: { versions: { include: :user } })
end
```

My problem is that I get all the versions for each item, when I only want the latest version. I'm not sure how to do this with regards to PaperTrail. Here are my models:

Subclassed `PaperTrail::Version` class and gave it an association to `User` as such:

```
class Version < PaperTrail::Version
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
end
```

... User has a has_many association to Version.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :versions, :foreign_key => 'whodunnit', :class_name => "Version"
end
```

Items model using PaperTrail gem

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail versions: {
    class_name: "Version"
  }
end
```

Now I just need to limit the versions I'm fetching to the last version, i.e., if an item has 30 versions, I want the last item inserted into the table. From reading the ActiveRecord docs, a `has_many` association should help me here, but if I do this in my Item model

```
has_many :last_version, -> { order('created_at DESC').last }, class_name: 'Version', foreign_key: :item_id
```

...and then use that in my includes -> `@items = Item.all.includes(last_version: :user)`

I get an error:

`ArgumentError (#<Version id: 1, item_type: "Item", item_id: 1, event: "create", whodunnit: "1", object: nil> is not an ActiveRecord::Relation):`

**Update**
I was doing it wrong by chaining `last` on `order`. If I remove `last` and put `limit(1)` instead, it compiles fine.

```
has_many :last_version, -> { order('created_at DESC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Version', foreign_key: :item_id
```

The version select looks fine too, note the limit:

```sql
Item Load (35.7ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items
  Version Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `versions`.* FROM `versions` WHERE `versions`.`item_type` = 'Item' AND `versions`.`item_id` IN (...) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, when I try to include the scope on the console as such:
`Item.includes(:latest_version).as_json(include: :latest_version)`
... all the items have an empty `latest_versions` array except for 1. Why is this? Starting to lose some hair!

Anyone have any ideas?

I've also tried putting the scope on `has_paper_trail` as per the docs, but I get the exact same result, except just with an empty `versions` array, except for one item. Hmmmmfff

[The PaperTrail docs I mentioned earlier](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#5b-configuring-the-versions-association)

**Update 2**

I managed to fix it with a `has_one` association. Credit to [How to fix this n+1 query: Limiting child association to most recent record in JSON api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598894/how-to-fix-this-n1-query-limiting-child-association-to-most-recent-record-in-j)

Mine looks like:

```
has_one :last_version, -> { order('created_at DESC') }, class_name: "Version", foreign_key: :item_id
```

It does load all the versions on each item eagerly, but avoids an N+1 query and I end up with the most recent version on each item.

If anyone has an idea of how to optimize this even further, I'm all ears, but for now, this will work.

Comment: I am using rails 5.1.7 and PaperTrial gem 10.3.1

Comment: I think you have done very well for being new to rails! :) There are a lot of moving parts here. Your solution puts the complexity in the model layer. I would probably try to put the complexity in `get_items` instead, even if that meant I couldn't use `as_json`. But, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, it's all a bit magical at the moment and I could really do with a crash course. :-) I decided to put it in the model as there is no flow involved, just data fetching. It felt like the natural place for it. It's the eternal problem with MVC though. :-) I'll definitely revisit the approach once the things start to fatten out a bit more.